# Multi line checkbox text formatting

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a checkbox with long text (about 5 or 6 lines).  I'm trying to get the text indented and nicely aligned when it is wrapped.  My current code works currently in IE but in Chrome, Safari, FireFox, the text is on a different line than the checkbox is.  Does anyone know what I can be doing wrong here or have any other ways to accomplish this?  Thanks for any help in advance!

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Info.ascx.cs"
Inherits="Project.Info" %>
<style type="text/css">
.CkbxFormat input
{
    float: left;
}
.CkbxFormat label
{
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 50px;">
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="700px" CellSpacing="2" CellPadding="5"
    Style="border: Solid 1px green;">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Information"></asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CkBxInfo" runat="server" Text="The accessor of a property contains the executable statements associated with getting (reading or computing) or setting (writing) the property. The accessor declarations can contain a get accessor, a set accessor, or both.  The body of the get accessor is similar to that of a method. It must return a value of the property type. The execution of the get accessor is equivalent to reading the value of the field. " CssClass="CkbxFormat"></asp:CheckBox>
        </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the CSS:

```
.CkbxFormat label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}
.CkbxFormat input {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}
```

I think that will get you very close to what you want.